# How to make exe file run from r script wait for keyboard input?

Tags: c++, r, cmd

I have an R script that calls an exe file of a c++ program. I would like the c++ program to pause at some point. Then the r script should perform some further computation as additional input for the c++ program. Then the c++ program should finish.

I was thinking of using the R KeyboardSimulator package to resume the c++ program at the right time, but it doesn't pause when executed from inside the R script.

```
# some R code

system("myProgram.exe withAdditionalArguments")

    // inside c++ program
    system("pause");

# more R code to produce new file

    // rest of c++ program

# finish R script
```

PS. Any different solution to pause and resume the program at the right time is also fine, I just want to avoid having to split my program into 2.

Comment: How do you want to pass the computed values to the C++ program?

Comment: I will save them into a new file that the c++ program will read

Comment: You could make the C++ program wait for the file.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, didn't even think of this approach